# Searching embedded documents in array with Mongoose / Node.js

Tags: mongodb, node.js, mongoose

[image]
My Schema and data is shown above. How can I query in `Mongoose` for all documents where within `optedOutPerson` where `campaign_id` contains `6020`?

In MongoHub, I'm trying: `{ 'optedOutPerson.campaign_id': /602/ }` and that yields no results.

Thank you, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems you are storing the campaign id as a ObjectID, try convert to string